# Going through a dictionary Python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, filter, format

I am trying to write a for loop that goes through the SavedStrats dict and prints out the Exchange for each account and strategy.

Inside SavedStrats dict:

```
{'Account1': {'MACDStrategy2.0': OrderedDict([('Exchange', 'Bybit'),
                                              ('Script', 'MomentumStrats'),
                                              ('StratStatus', 'ACTIVE')]),
              'STDandRegressionStrategy': OrderedDict([('Exchange', 'Bybit'),
                                                       ('Script',
                                                        'MomentumStrats'),
                                                       ('StratStatus',
                                                        'ACTIVE')])},
 'Account2': {'BollingerBandStrategy': OrderedDict([('Exchange', 'Bybit'),
                                                    ('Script',
                                                     'MomentumStrats'),
                                                    ('StratStatus',
                                                     'PAUSED ')])}}
```

Code:

```
for account in Savedstrats:
    print(account)
    for strats in account[0]:
       print(strats, " Exchnage: ", strats['StratStatus'])
```

Expected Output:

```
Account1
MACDStrategy2.0 Strat Status: ACTIVE
STDandRegressionStrategy Strat Status: ACTIVE
Account2
BollingerBandStrategy Strat Status: PAUSED
```

Comment: Please stop this

Comment: How can I delete someone else's comment?

Comment: @ChristopherOjo only mods can (i think). But you can always flag a comment if you think any comments are inadequate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
for k, v in SavedStrats.items():
    print(k)
    for s, d in v.items():
        print(s, "Strat Status:", d["StratStatus"])
```

Prints:

```
Account1
MACDStrategy2.0 Strat Status: ACTIVE
STDandRegressionStrategy Strat Status: ACTIVE
Account2
BollingerBandStrategy Strat Status: PAUSED
```